# How do i build CURL with smtp support on Windows?

Tags: curl, libcurl

i'm trying to sond emails with CURL (smtp) but i get

```
 Protocol "'smtp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

How can i build CURL with smtp? I don't need SSH or SSL support, i just need to download files and send email with CURL using the command line.

I tried with Visual Studio but it still gives me the same error

Comment: You have a stray single quote first in your URL, remove it!

Comment: Why do you want to use `curl`? SMTP support in cURL is clunky at best - no MX lookups, need for crafter URLs to allow what was born as a stateless HTTP client to use stateful SMTP. I'd suggest you checked out, say, https://www.raymond.cc/blog/sending-email-using-command-line-useful-for-downtime-alert-notification/